# Add FilePart body to webTestClient during Integration Test

Tags: asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have the following controller on a spring reactive project:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers/profile")
class CustomerProfileVerificationController(private val CustomerProfileVerificationService: ProfileVerificationService) {

    @PostMapping("/verify", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
    fun verifyCustomerProfile(
        @RequestPart incomingImage: FilePart,
    ): Mono<CustomerProfileVerificationResult> =
        CustomerProfileVerificationService.executeCustomerProfileVerification(incomingImage)
}
```

And the integration test:

```
@Test
fun `given a valid request then return the verification result`() {

   
    val partName = "incomingImage"
    val builder = MultipartBodyBuilder()
    builder.part(partName, ClassPathResource("/test/resources/source-1"), MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    val parts = builder.build().toSingleValueMap()
  

    // When calling the endpoint
    webTestClient
        .post()
        .uri("/customers/profile/verify")
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         .body(Mono.just(parts), FilePart::class.java)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        .isOk
}
```

After running the test I received the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
...
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
...
Caused by: reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:276)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:425)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.ensureBufferValid(NativePRNG.java:528)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:547)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:221)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:758)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:815)
    at java.base/java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:323)
    at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.generateMultipartBoundary(MimeTypeUtils.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartWriterSupport.generateMultipartBoundary(MultipartWriterSupport.java:89)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.PartHttpMessageWriter.write(PartHttpMessageWriter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$write$11(BodyInserters.java:404)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.write(BodyInserters.java:404)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.writeWithMessageWriters(BodyInserters.java:379)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$fromProducer$2(BodyInserters.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest.writeTo(DefaultClientRequestBuilder.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$exchange$1(ExchangeFunctions.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WiretapConnector.lambda$connect$0(WiretapConnector.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.doConnect(HttpHandlerConnector.java:114)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.lambda$connect$0(HttpHandlerConnector.java:81)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    ... 9 more
```

Question: What is the correct and **non-blocking** way to add the FilePart file into the webTestClient.body?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should be receiving class cast exception with following code

> body(Mono.just(parts), FilePart::class.java)

Here parts is of type Map<String, HttpEntity<?>> while you are providing class of element in publisher as FilPart.

Instead of you providing the element class, can you try
`.bodyValue(Mono.just(parts))`

This is working fine for "multipart/form-data" with WebTestClient.